# React Router: Load non-index route with babel-standalone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to build a React app using `babel-standalone` instead of proper Babel transpiling (to make it easier for non-Node users to customize without having to transpile).

Here's my setup (you'll have to run this locally due to StackOverflow sandboxing):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react@16.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router@3.2.0/umd/ReactRouter.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'></div>
    <script type='text/babel'>
      const App = props => (
        <ReactRouter.Router history={ReactRouter.browserHistory}>
          <ReactRouter.Route path='/' component={A} />
          <ReactRouter.Route path='/b' component={B} />
        </ReactRouter.Router>
      )

      const Link = ReactRouter.Link
      const A = props => <h1><Link to='/b'>Link to B</Link></h1>
      const B = props => <h1>Welcome to B</h1>

      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works fine for linking from component `A` to `B`. However, if I link to `B` then refresh the page, I get a 404 from my static server. Is there a way to fix this such that route `B` will load if a user requests `host_address/b`? Any suggestions would be greatly helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm happy enough using the `hashHistory` argument to `history`, which stores all routes in `/#/` and therefore allows refreshes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react@16.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router@3.2.0/umd/ReactRouter.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'></div>
    <script type='text/babel'>
      const App = props => (
        <ReactRouter.Router history={ReactRouter.hashHistory}>
          <ReactRouter.Route path='/' component={A} />
          <ReactRouter.Route path='/b' component={B} />
        </ReactRouter.Router>
      )

      const Link = ReactRouter.Link
      const A = props => <h1><Link to='/b'>Link to B</Link></h1>
      const B = props => <h1>Welcome to B</h1>

      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After writing the above, I remembered solving this problem on S3 by setting index.html as the html page to serve for requests *and for errors* -- it's a hack but it allows one to avoid hash-banged urls